# How can I open .obj files with color in python?

Tags: python, .obj

I tend to load the .obj file with its color in python and save it as png. I had many searches, but none were suitable for my purpose.
[here](https://github.com/pclausen/obj2png) is the code I found for saving as a png file:

and output appears like this:

[image]

but the desired output is like this one:
[image]

or this one:
[image]

Any help, please.

Comment: How are you going to elaborate the .objs?

Comment: I downloaded some 3d models from here: https://free3d.com/3d-models/ikea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer in the [vedo](https://vedo.embl.es/) library
it can be installed easily:

```
pip install vedo
```

by these simple codes, this output came out:

```
from vedo import *

mesh = Mesh("data/10055_Gray_Wolf_v1_L3.obj",)

mesh.texture("data/10055_Gray_Wolf_Diffuse_v1.jpg", scale=0.1)

mesh.show()
```

[image]

I downloaded 3d obj file by its texture from [here](https://free3d.com/).